# PostgreSQL RANK() function over aggregated column

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, rank

I'm constructing quite complex query, where I try to load users with their aggregated points altogether with their rank. I found the RANK() function that could help me to achieve this but can't get it working.

Here's the query that is working without RANK:

```
SELECT users.*, SUM(received_points.count) AS pts 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN received_points ON received_points.user_id = users.id AND ...other joining conditions... 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY pts DESC NULLS LAST
```

Now I would like to select also the rank - but this way using RANK function it's not working:

```
SELECT users.*, SUM(received_points.count) AS pts, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY pts DESC NULLS LAST) AS position
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN received_points ON received_points.user_id = users.id AND ...other joining conditions... 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY pts DESC NULLS LAST
```

It tells: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "pts" does not exist`

I guess I get whole concept of window functions wrong. How can I select the rank of user sorted by aggregated value like `pts` in example above?

*I know I can assign ranks manually afterwards but what if I want to also filter the rows according to users.name in query and still get user's rank in general (not-filtered) leaderboard...? Dont know if I'm clear...*

Comment: You can't use `pts` here as the alias doesn't exist yet (you can't reference an alias in the same `SELECT` it's defined). `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(received_points.count) DESC NULLS LAST)` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, man, now it looks great! :)

Comment: @Marth you should add your comment as an answer. Many people skip comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Marth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650437/marth) suggested in his comment:

> You can't use `pts` here as the alias doesn't exist yet (you can't reference an alias in the same `SELECT` it's defined). `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(received_points.count) DESC NULLS LAST)` should work fine.